# Citing and printing references from another tex file

Tags: biblatex, citing, multiple-files

I have two tex files, `tex1.tex` and `tex2.tex`. I have defined multiple `bibitem`s on `tex1.tex` and printed the bibliography there. Is it possible to reference some of the biblatex items from `tex1` in `tex2`, and print the corresponding referenced items in `tex2`?

MWE:

`tex1.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

I'm citing~\cite{cite2} first and then~\cite{cite1}

% I could also manually write the bibitems here
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{tex1_biblio}

\end{document}
```

`tex1_biblio.bib`:

```
@article{cite1,
    author =       "Author1",
    title =        "Title1",
    journal =      "Journal1",
    volume =       "8",
    number =       "20",
    pages =        "888",
    year =         "2000",
    DOI =          ""
}

@article{cite2,
    author =       "Author2",
    title =        "Title2",
    journal =      "Journal2",
    volume =       "3",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "77",
    year =         "2010",
    DOI =          ""
}
```

`tex2.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}

\section{Sec1}
I'm citing~\cite{cite1} from mwe1 (shoud be [2])

\printbibliography % (?)

\section{Sec2}
I'm citing~\cite{cite1} from mwe1 (shoud be [2])

\printbibliography % (?)

\end{document}
```

So, if I `cite` `[2]` (from `tex1`) in `tex2`, I have a bibliography as

```
[2] ref 2 from tex 1 ...
```

If this is possible, would it be also possible to print these references in `tex2` multiple times? (for example, for different sections)

I'm aware of the `xcite` package but I can't figure out how to make it work and I think it doesn't allow me to print the bibliography on a different tex file

Comment: I'm not aware of any such method, though your account is pretty sketchy so I'm not completely sure. What is the motivation for this, though? It may be that there are other possibilities to achieve (more or less) what you are looking for.

Comment: Sketchy? I'm asking because I was writing a paper and I need to use some of its references (using the same citation numbers) in a letter about that paper, and I didn't want to copy and paste the refs manually from the PDF file :o

Comment: Well, I wondered if there was a real TeX-related reason as opposed to just an *ad hoc* one. The 'problem' you face is why BibTeX (et cetera) was invented, after all. Failing that, I'd be inclined to harness the power of `grep` to make the cutting and pasting even more painless. However, it is possible someone else has an answer.

Comment: @jon I don't think BibTeX would especially help, would it? Not directly. I mean, if you were using BibTeX, you could, I think, solve the problem quite elegantly, but I wouldn't say it is part of its purpose to solve it.

Comment: @cfr -- Surely, the (or 'a') point of BibTeX is to make it so you don't have 'to copy and paste the refs manually' from one file to the next?

Comment: @jon Yes. But that is not really the problem here. The problem is to get the numerical labels to match those assigned to sources in the paper, given that only a subset will be referenced in the letter and not necessarily in the same order. If you just use BibTeX with the same style and `.bib`, you won't get e.g. `4` and `6` but, say, `2` and `1` or whatever.

Comment: @cfr -- That may be a fairly minor problem that is easily sorted out depending on a number of factors (such as the bibliography style) that are still unclear (`bibitems` and `biblatex`?). Of course, I did not mean to suggest that one need only 'just use BibTeX' and all problems are instantly solved. But I still suspect a BibTeX/Biber solution is possible. (Or, maybe, just use `grep` and figure out what number to put in the optional argument of `\bibitem` --- if in fact `\bibitems` are being used.)

Comment: @jon I wasn't disagreeing. I only meant what I said. I didn't mean anything more.

Comment: What method do you use for your bibliography? Your question body mentions `bibitem`, yet your question is tagged `biblatex`. The `bibitems` makes me think of a manual approach with which `biblatex` is not compatible. Can you please clarify your question? (By help of an MWE, if you like.)

Comment: @moewe Thanks or the help, I added a mwe. Basically, I want to use the citations from `tex1` so they appear in `tex2` with the same numbering as `tex1` references. I'm not sure if using `biblatex` in `tex2`

Comment: Is it possible to use `biblatex` in `tex1`? Will both files use the `article` class or something more specific?

Comment: I'm actually using `revtex4-1`, I'm not sure if that makes any difference

Comment: @DavidWinchester Use of `revtex4-1` does make a difference as it means `tex1` cannot have a bibliography generated by `biblatex` (`revtex4-1` also loads `natbib` and I think redefines `thebibliography` environment though that's less likely to limit possible solutions).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`tex1.tex` being the paper, upon which `bibtex` is run should look like a normal document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

I'm citing~\cite{cite2} first and then~\cite{cite1}

% I could also manually write the bibitems here
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{tex1_biblio}

\end{document}
```

`tex2.tex` can then make use of the [`xcite`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcite) package to use the same reference labels without generating a bibliography.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcite}
\externalcitedocument{tex1}

\begin{document}
\section{Sec1}
I'm citing~\cite{cite1} from mwe1 (shoud be [2])

\section{Sec2}
I'm citing~\cite{cite1} from mwe1 (shoud be [2])

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or if the bibliography should be replicated in its entirity then `\input{tex1.bbl}` can be used.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\section{Sec1}
I'm citing~\cite{cite1} from mwe1 (shoud be [2])

\section{Sec2}
I'm citing~\cite{cite1} from mwe1 (shoud be [2])

\input{tex1.bbl}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To generate references with the same labels as `tex1` but only print those used in `tex2` then [`xcite`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcite) should be used to determine the labels and then a separate bibliography needs to be generated.  To use the same labels we can do the below (this is not a very robust solution and may well break with use of any other bibliography-related packages or different bibliography styles) where the bibliography label for every entry is generated from a `\cite` command which extracts the relevant number from `tex1`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcite}
\externalcitedocument{tex1}

\let\oldbibitem\bibitem
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[1]{\oldbibitem[\cite{#1}]{#1}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Sec1}
I'm citing~\cite{cite1} from mwe1 (shoud be [2])

\section{Sec2}
I'm citing~\cite{cite1} from mwe1 (shoud be [2])

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{tex1_biblio}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. Using the `tex1.bbl` file prints all the references. Is it possible to only print the ones used on `tex2.tex`?

Comment: @DavidWinchester see my edit for one (hacky) method, I've also updated the answer generally as it was somewhat erroneous beforehand with what `xcite` and `\input{tex1.bbl}` were actually needed for.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer (the last part)! I have been looking for ages until I finally found this. However, on overleaf I get an error `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]` every other time I compile. Any ideas why, or how I can get rid of it?

Comment: And a second question: Let's say in tex2 I cite the references [5], [2], and [7] from tex1 (in that order). In the "References" of tex2, they are then listed in the order 5>2>7. I there a way to sort the references in tex2, such that they appear as [2], [5], [7] in the bibliography of tex2?

Comment: @Nayunis No idea on the error, may be Overleaf-specific, but as said this solution is likely to break quickly with other bibliography styles and packages.  That said it's not an error to ignore.  If you can reproduce with an MWE locally (not on overleaf) I can only suggest asking a new question.  As far as the ordering of the bibliography, `\nocite` at the start of `tex2.tex` is probably the easiest idea unless `tex1` has a sorted bibliography in which case something to match it like `abbrv` _may_ work for `tex2`.