# Customize bibtex numbering keeping the order in the References sections

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I would like to change the numbering of the reference in the text, as it is solved in this question: [How to customize bibtex numbering in a document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378160/how-to-customize-bibtex-numbering-in-a-document)
without altering the order in which references are shown.

For example:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@book{Knuth1984texbook,
    Author = {Knuth, D.E.},
    Title = {The TEXbook, volume A of Computers and typesetting},
    Year = {1984}}

@book{Chomsky1957,
    Address = {The Hague},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {Mouton},
    Title = {Syntactic Structures},
    Year = {1957}}

@book{Chomsky1965,
    Address = {Cambridge Mass.},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {{MIT} Press},
    Title = {Aspects of the Theory of Syntax},
    Year = {1965}}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\SetLabelAlign{bibright}{\hss\llap{[#1]}}
\newcounter{mynum}
\newcommand\mycite[2]{[#1]\setcounter{mynum}{0}\addtocounter{mynum}{#1-1}\refstepcounter{mynum}\label{#2}}
\newcommand\mybib[1]{\item[\ref{#1}]\bibentry{#1}}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}

This document is an example of \texttt{thebibliography} environment using 
 bibliography management. Three items are cited: \emph{Syntactic Structures} 
book \mycite{6}{Chomsky1957}, \emph{Aspects} \mycite{4}{Chomsky1965}, and  
Donald Knuth's TeXBook \mycite{10}{Knuth1984texbook}. The Linguistics related items are
[\ref{Chomsky1965},\ref{Chomsky1957}].
\medskip
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\nobibliography{\jobname}
\begin{itemize}[labelwidth=!,labelsep=1em,align=bibright]
\mybib{Chomsky1957}
\mybib{Chomsky1965}
\mybib{Knuth1984texbook}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

would create this:

[image]

Meaning that the order is altered, I would like that the references are shown in their normal ordering, that is:
[4]
[6]
[10]

Thank you for your help!

---

edit:

I would like to use this kind of behaviour for my compendium thesis. There are 6 publications that I want with the specific numbering 1 to 6 because they are the main papers composing the thesis. Even if they do not appear in that order in the text I would need that they are cited as 1,2,3,4,5,6. After that, the rest of citations (around 150) can have any ordering and of course I would not like to input them manually.

Comment: You could change the order in the itemize environment: `\begin{itemize}[labelwidth=!,labelsep=1em,align=bibright]
\mybib{Chomsky1965}
\mybib{Chomsky1957}
\mybib{Knuth1984texbook}
\end{itemize}` Should gve you the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

In this solution to the problem, the bibliography is manually created, in that each item is simply in the order listed in the `itemize` environment. So you can simply reorder the elements in the list environment and to match the numeric order.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\SetLabelAlign{bibright}{\hss\llap{[#1]}}
\newcounter{mynum}
\newcommand\mycite[2]{[#1]\setcounter{mynum}{0}\addtocounter{mynum}{#1-1}\refstepcounter{mynum}\label{#2}}
\newcommand\mybib[1]{\item[\ref{#1}]\bibentry{#1}}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}

This document is an example of \texttt{thebibliography} environment using 
 bibliography management. Three items are cited: \emph{Syntactic Structures} 
book \mycite{6}{Chomsky1957}, \emph{Aspects} \mycite{4}{Chomsky1965}, and  
Donald Knuth's TeXBook \mycite{10}{Knuth1984texbook}. The Linguistics related items are
[\ref{Chomsky1965},\ref{Chomsky1957}].
\medskip
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\nobibliography{\jobname}
\begin{itemize}[labelwidth=!,labelsep=1em,align=bibright]
\mybib{Chomsky1965}
\mybib{Chomsky1957}
\mybib{Knuth1984texbook}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for your answer. Does it mean that I have to add manually all my bibliography? I mean, there are like 8 entries that I want to have with a fixed number and then, around 150 that I do not care

Comment: @AuroraGonzálezVidal The solution is meant for a very specific purpose: to allow references to specific entries in one document in another document, so yes, it is designed to be manual. If you have a larger bibliography, it's very unclear why you want some to be fixed.  Maybe you could explain a bit more in your question what your specific problem is, because it sounds like this solution isn't appropriate for what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks @Alan, I think I have clarified it. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

> *Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355331/189125*

As already said in my previous answer to [How to customize bibtex numbering in a document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378160/how-to-customize-bibtex-numbering-in-a-document), you can use the `xcite` package to import the citation from another file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcite}
\externalcitedocument{document2}

\let\oldbibitem\bibitem
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[1]{\oldbibitem[\cite{#1}]{#1}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cite{bertram}
\cite{angenendt}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer but I think I cannot reproduce the example you have given since I do not have document2 available

Comment: @AuroraGonzálezVidal The idea is that you have two documents: one with its own bibliography (call this `document2`) which has its own bibliography, and the document you want to use selected references in.  So `document2` in this example is the other document that has the references you want to copy into the new document.