# Print out only selected entries from bibliography latex

Tags: bibtex, overleaf

I have a paper with a main.tex and supmat.tex file in overleaf.

The supmat.tex file needs to cite papers from the original paper.

I reprint references in the end of the paper after compiling main and they print out as expected with the main file being the reference point for their numbering. I use:

```
{\newpage
\small
\bibliographystyle{ieee_fullname}
\bibliography{references}
}
```

However, I would like that when I print them on the supmat.tex file, to only display the entries used in this document but respecting their initial numbering. (I have no problem manually choosing them if needed.)

(In any static word like program you would just delete entries you don't need but here I've lost so much time trying to figure out how to do it programmatically that it's frustrating.)

Thanks,

Comment: Try [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355331/106162)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is this really related to Overleaf? If not, consider removing the tag.

Comment: Are all your `suppmat.tex` citations included in `main.tex`?